# Android Adapter to gridView - List of Buttons instead of List names of Buttons

Tags: android, gridview, android-adapter, baseadapter

In many examples and tutorials - how to use gridView and adapter is the case that in our Adapter we implement some List of for example names of items in gridView.

We override method getView in Adapter. Then we Inflate our item in gridView. Next we changing it text to text from our list[position]

Here is example of code:

public class TileAdapter  extends BaseAdapter{

```
private Context context;
private Tile[] tiles;

public TileAdapter(Context context, Tile[] tiles){
    this.context = context;
    this.tiles= tiles;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View gridView;

    if(convertView == null){

        gridView = new View(context);
        gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_tile, null);

        TextView textView = (TextView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.tile_title);
        textView.setText(tiles[position].getTitle());

    }else{
        gridView = (View) convertView;
    }

    return gridView;

}
```

Everything is working fine. But what if I need to create items from list of it?

Let's assume we have somewhere `List<Button> buttons` where we have our buttons which we also using in other classes. GridView Adapter gets from the "MainClass" this list.

**How to code `getView()` in Adapter to set as items our buttons from this list?**
So to not creating new Buttons, and telling that the label of new Button is the same as in the list, but to put in gridView exatcly this buttons from list!

So i need something like this? You know the idea?

**Field is my class which extending Button**

```
@Override

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if(convertView == null){

            view= new View(context);
            view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.field_layout, null);

            //This is bad - but You know what i want?
            Field field = (Field) view.findViewById(R.id.field);
            field = fields.get(position);

        }else{
            view= (View) convertView;
        }

        return view;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is forcing you to inflate all the items when `getView()` is called.
Instead you can create/receive the list of views when you create the adapter and return them.

So an example of this would be:

```
public class TileAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    List<View> views = new ArrayList<>();

    public void setViews(@NonNull List<View> views) {
        this.views = views;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return views.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return views.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        return views.get(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't get it.
What is this views, and how to inflate this buttons from list?

Comment: A view can be inflated like you did in `inflater.inflate(R.layout.field_layout, null);` You can inflate them in your activity and pass them to the adapter or in the adapter constructor. Maybe you should read this before you continue - http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidCustomViews/article.html